# Bluemix Cloud Foundry REST API

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud, swagger, cloud-foundry

Can I access [Cloud Foundry REST API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/237/) on Bluemix? If yes, how can I access it (cannot find any documentation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the Cloud Foundry REST API on Bluemix as you would normally do with CF. In addition to that, if you need it and you are already familiar with *cf curl* you can take a look at the *bluemix curl* command. For example if you want to retrieve the information for all organizations of the current account:

```
bluemix curl /v2/organizations
```

Please see the [Docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/index.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am now able to access to the CF API using https://api.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/v2/info. It retrieves the URL to get the auth token (POST https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token). And then with the token I can interact with CF REST API.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access CF API you have to get the authentication token. Then add it to each request in the headers.

```
oauthTokenResponse = requests.post(
  f'https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=cf',
  data={'username': <your username>, 'password': <your password>, 'client_id': 'cf'},
  auth=('cf', '')
)
auth = oauthTokenResponse.json()['token_type'] + ' ' + oauthTokenResponse.json()['access_token']

appsResponse = requests.get(f'{self.api_endpoint}/v2/apps',
  headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': auth}
)

apps = json.loads(appsResponse.content)
```