# IBM Cloud REST API - documentation?

Tags: ibm-cloud

**I would like to create Compose instances programmatically on IBM Cloud.** Is there any REST API documentation?

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/11/opening-the-compose-api-on-the-ibm-cloud/) is the link to the article about Compose API. The author mentioned: "If you want to create new Compose database services on IBM Cloud, use the IBM Cloud bx commands or use equivalent REST APIs."

That's nice and I would really like to use it but the question is **where is the documentation of equivalent REST API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivelant api is the Cloud Foundry API on Bluemix.

You will find information about accessing it in this stack overflow question - [Bluemix Cloud Foundry REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520248/bluemix-cloud-foundry-rest-api)

The api itself is documented here - https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/237/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the best place to start learning about the IBM Cloud API is:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs?tab=api-docs

From there you can find the API of each IBM Cloud service that offers an API.

Since the body of the question is specifically asking for a infrastructure as code solution, please have a look at the [IBM Cloud Schematics service](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/schematics?topic=schematics-getting-started) that is based on Terraform.